# Shift+Return en Python

Tags: python, teclado

Tengo el siguiente trozo que escribe en Wpp Web un mensaje, pero cuando hago `("\n")` en vez de hacer un salto de linea me envia el mensaje.
Como hago para que sea `Shift+("\n")`

Ejemplo del codigo

```
msjFechaTurno = '*'+'Fecha turno(Año-mes-dia):'+'*'+ fechaTurno +("\n")
```

Comment: ¿Como interactuas con wpp web? ¿Selenium?

Comment: Si si, con Selenium y Chromium

Answer (score 1):

Basta con que usando [`selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.send_keys`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html) envíes la combinación `Keys.SHIFT + Keys.ENTER`. Estas constantes se encuentran en el módulo 
[`selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.keys.html?highlight=selenium.webdriver.common.keys.keys#selenium.webdriver.common.keys.Keys).

Algo así:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains



driver = webdriver.Chrome()
actions = ActionChains(driver) 

fecha_turno = "2020-03-24"
msj_fecha_turno = f'*Fecha turno(Año-mes-dia):*{fecha_turno}'
actions.send_keys(msj_fecha_turno)
actions.send_keys(Keys.SHIFT + Keys.ENTER)
actions.perform()
```

Igualmente, cuando quieras enviar simplemente debes hacer:

```
actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
actions.perform()
```

Realmente se podría usar directamente el carácter Unicode, pero usar las constantes es más legible...